# React - Rendering a graph with DOM nodes and SVG lines

Tags: svg, reactjs

I have N DOM nodes displayed inline and following the natural document flow. Some nodes are connected visually with SVG lines.

I have data looking something like this:

```
nodes: [node1, node2, node3, node4, node5, ...]

links: {
    link1: [node1, node2],
    link2: [node3, node4],
    link3: [node3, node5],
    ...
}
```

The SVG lines should update correctly when the document reflows.

How should I approach this using React?

Answer (score 0):

Well, You've been lucky. No comments tho.

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/Theadd/pen/xwgmrq?editors=101)

`No dependencies other than react v0.14.0-rc1 and react-dom`

Answer (score 0):

If this is still actual, you could use [react-sigma](http://npmjs.com/package/react-sigma) to display network graph with your data (nodes and links vairables), considering that every node has property "id":

```
import {Sigma, RandomizeNodePositions, RelativeSize, ForceAtlas2} from 'react-sigmajs'
...
render() {
  let edges = Object.keys(links).map(id => ({id, source: links[id][0].id, target: links[id][1].id}))
  return <Sigma graph={{nodes, edges}}>
    <RandomizeNodePositions/>
    <RelativeSize initialSize={10}/>
    <ForceAtlas2/>
  </Sigma>
}
```

```js
let graph = {nodes: [{id: "n1"}, {id:"n2"}], edges: [{id:"e1", source:"n1", target:"n2"}]}
let Graph = React.createElement(Sigma.Sigma, {graph}, [
 React.createElement(Sigma.RandomizeNodePositions, {key: 0}), 
 React.createElement(Sigma.RelativeSize, {initialSize:10, key: 1}), 
 React.createElement(Sigma.ForceAtlas2, {key: 2}), ])
ReactDOM.render(
  Graph,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-sigma@1.2/dist/react-sigma.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```